# How to get one item from a listView after click listener

Tags: android

Please don't make it duplicate.

Hey everyone... I have asked this question before but nobody solve my problem. Here is my problem:
I want to perform the search action. In which data will be fetched from database and will be shown in listView. After clicking the one username it will pass his userID to second activity to show his Profile. The data include userID, username, gender, and address but only one item userID will be passed to second activity. 
I have searched so many tutorials but found nothing like this.

I repeat again, please don't make it duplicate.

Here is my code:

```
    listView.setAdapter(adapterSearchElements);

    adapterSearchElements = new AdapterSearchElements(this, R.layout.searchresultcutomrow);
    listView.setAdapter(adapterSearchElements);
    json_string = getIntent().getExtras().getString("json_data");

    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
        jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");

        int count = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < jsonArray.length(); k++) {
            //    while (count < jsonArray.length()) {
           // JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);

            JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(k)));

            user_id = JO.getString("user_id");
            name = JO.getString("name");
            Gender = JO.getString("Gender");
            address = JO.getString("address");
            final SearchResultsElements searchResultsElements = new SearchResultsElements(user_id,name, Gender, address);
            adapterSearchElements.add(searchResultsElements);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {

                 //   String userid=searchResultsElements.getUser_id();

                  //  final String item = (String)parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position);


                    Intent i = new Intent(DisplaySearchResults.this, FriendsProfile.class);

                    i.putExtra("user_id", user_id);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
             // count++;

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Which part are you having a problem with exactly? Is it only figuring out how to get the correct user Id to pass to the new activity or is the `ListView` also not displaying correctly?

Comment: listView is displaying correctly but i want to pass the selected userID to second activity not his name or address but only userID

Comment: I want to know how to get the selected user id from a listView and pass it to second activity @GeorgeMulligan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to look up the `SearchResultsElements` at the position passed into the `listView.setOnItemClickListener()` callback like the following:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {

        SearchResultsElements selectedSearchResultsElements = adapterSearchElements.getItem(position);
        Intent i = new Intent(DisplaySearchResults.this, FriendsProfile.class);

        i.putExtra("user_id", selectedSearchResultsElements.getUser_id());
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

I used the adapter here to look up the item. You can also use `listView.getItemAtPosition(position);` if you cast the returned object to the correct type.

Comment: Thank You so much . its working now . i think nobody here knows the correct the correct answer but you ... amazing @George Mulligan

Answer (score 0):

If you get your elements from a database think of using CursorAdapter.